# Does the "Agony Touch" stack with a Ghost's Draining Touch?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, undead

Ghostwalk introduces, among others, a feat called "Agony Touch". This Special Ability allows the ghost that takes it to deal 1d4 ability damage to a target, to a physical ability chosen at time of taking this feat.
However, many ghosts also have the inborn ability "Draining Touch", which allows a Ghost to drain 1d4 ability points from a single ability score of its target.
Does Agony Touch stack with Draining Touch? Or is it merely a way for Ghosts without this ability to gain a weaker version of it through feats?

Answer (score 1):

## The short answer: No

*Ghostwalk* on Feats, in part, says, "Unless otherwise stated, ghost feats are supernatural abilities" (28). So, although the feat **Agony Touch**, in part, says, "You can make a touch attack that deals 1d4 points of temporary ability damage to the selected ability score of a target" (8), making that touch attack is using a supernatural ability as a separate and unique standard action that's typically incompatible with other attacks.

In other words, a traditional [ghost](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#ghost) (*Monster Manual* 116–18) like the question describes could *either* take a standard action to employ the feat Agony Touch *or* make its normal incorporeal touch attack or attacks and, because of the specificity of the supernatural ability **draining touch**, have each of its normal incorporeal touch attacks deal that 1d4 points of ability damage.

### The long answer: A *Monster Manual* ghost typically can't use *Ghostwalk* ghost feats

*Ghostwalk* on **A Ghost Is Not a Ghost** says

> The *Monster Manual* describes a ghost as a restless spirit that for some reason cannot give up its ties to the living and haunts a particular location or item. These ghosts are undead creatures of many different types (humanoids, giants, magical beasts, and so on) and have many strange powers that make them incredibly dangerous combatants. Furthermore, killing them is usually only a temporary solution, for they rejuvenate and return to their old haunts.
>
> The ghosts described in this book are not that kind of ghost.…
>
> Whenever this book [i.e. *Ghostwalk*] refers to a “ghost,” it is not talking about a *Monster Manual* ghost.…
>
> To avoid confusion and preserve the flavor of this campaign [setting; i.e. the city of Manifest and its surrounding environs], undead ghosts should rarely, if ever, be used in the context of a game. The line between the spiritual dead (ghosts) and undead of any kind is a strong one in this setting, and including an undead sort of ghost blurs that line and reduces some of the impact of all undead being evil. (8)

Thus if the campaign allows *Ghostwalk* ghosts and *Monster Manual* ghosts, a distinction must be made between those creatures. Later, *Ghostwalk* on **Feats**, in part, says, "Feats with the [Ghost] descriptor can be used only by ghosts unfettered by a physical body" (28), making it so *Ghostwalk* ghosts can use feats with the ghost descriptor, but *Monster Manual* ghosts can't because, as above, "[w]henever [*Ghostwalk*] refers to a 'ghost,' it is not talking about a *Monster Manual* ghost," and the feat Agony Touch possesses the descriptor ghost.

---

***Note:** A cursory look through* Ghostwalk *didn't reveal to me any evidence that all undead are evil in that setting. Possibly Cook and Reynolds overlooked that* Monster Manual *ghosts in* Third Edition *can be any alignment? Alternatively, because* Ghostwalk *is a between-the-revision book (like* Savage Species, *for example), maybe they expected the* 3.5 *revision to change that? Maybe I just missed it? Anyway, I dunno where that* all undead being evil *thing comes from.*